# How to use itext 5 to get the length and width of the content in the PDF document

Tags: pdf, itext

How to use i text 5 to get the length and width of the content in the PDF document? In another word,

[image]

gets the length and width of the red rectangle in the image

Comment: So you have an existing PDF and want the bounding rectangle of its text content on a given page?

Comment: You might want to look at the iText example [ShowTextMargins](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-15#579-showtextmargins.java).

Answer (score 0):

This answer to this question can be found on the FAQ section of the iText website.

http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-find-out-current-cursor-position-page

One way is to use document.add()

> [source itextpdf.com]
>
> There is a very old method called getVerticalPosition() that takes a
>   boolean as parameter. I'm not proud of that method as it is a getter
>   method that not only will give you the Y position on the page after
>   using a series of document.add() operations, it can also change the
>   current Y position (and that is not what a getter method should do).
>
> If you pass false as a parameter, it will give you the current Y,
>   which could be the position of the baseline of the last Chunk you've
>   added.
>
> If you pass true as a parameter, the method will first add a newline
>   and give you the position of the baseline of the "next" line of text
>   you'll be adding.

Comment: Edited the answer with a direct quote from the website.